# Extension Method for Custom Attributes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reflection, extension-methods, custom-attributes

I am working an ASP.net MVC4 website and have model & view model layer. *Because of certain reasons* I have different names for few properties in Model and ViewModel

**Model**

```
public partial class Project
{
   public string Desc {get; set;}
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
   public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now at model layer, I need to use ViewModel name of a property if it is different. I was thinking of creating a custom attribute so that I can have something like this in models:

```
public partial class Project
{
    [ViewModelPropertyName("Description")]
    public string Desc {get;set;}
}
```

and use it at model layer as

```
string.Format("ViewModel Property Name is {0}", this.Desc.ViewModelPropertyName())
```

I want this to generic so that if there is no `ViewModelPropertyName` attribute on a property then it should return the same property name i.e. if `Desc` property has no attribute then it should return `"Desc"` only.

**Here is what I tried**

```
public class ViewModelPropertyNameAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    #region Fields

    string viewModelPropertyName;

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string GetViewModelPropertyName()
    {
        return viewModelPropertyName;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public ViewModelPropertyNameAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        this.viewModelPropertyName = propertyName;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Need help for how to access custom attribute

**Current state**

```
    public static class ModelExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ViewModelPropertyName(this Object obj)
    {
        // ERROR: Cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Reflect.Assembly'
        System.Attribute[] attrs = System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(obj);

        foreach (System.Attribute attr in attrs)
        {
            if (attr is ViewModelPropertyNameAttribute)
            {
                return ((ViewModelPropertyNameAttribute)attr).GetViewModelPropertyName();
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

But this has compile time error:

Comment: `this.Desc.ViewModelPropertyName` will need to be `this.Desc.GetViewModelPropertyName()`.  There is no such thing as an `extension property`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not get the attributes you used to decorate the properties by reflecting on the type of the property itself. I have therefore modified your *ViewModelPropertyName(this object)* Extension method slightly to take in the name of your desired property.

This method will now take in the name of the property whose attribute you wish to get. If the attribute exists it will return the value passed to its constructor, if it on the other hand, does not exist it will simply return the name of the property you passed in.

```
public static class ModelExtensionMethods
{
    public static string ViewModelPropertyName(this object obj, string name)
    {
        var attributes = obj.GetType()
                            .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                            .OfType<MetadataTypeAttribute>()
                            .First()
                            .MetadataClassType 
                            .GetProperty(name)
                            .GetCustomAttributes(true);

        if (attributes.OfType<ViewModelPropertyNameAttribute>().Any())
        {
            return attributes.OfType<ViewModelPropertyNameAttribute>()
                             .First()
                             .GetViewModelPropertyName();
        }
        else
        {
            return name;
        } 
    }
}
```

You can also define the following classes to test this new approach.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(TestClassMeta))]
class TestClass { }

class TestClassMeta
{
    [ViewModelPropertyName("TheName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Also, as you can see from the following lines of code, your *ViewModelPropertyName(this object, string)* Extension method will now be called on the instance of your TestClass, instead of calling it on the property itself.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new TestClass().ViewModelPropertyName("FirstName"));
        Console.WriteLine(new TestClass().ViewModelPropertyName("LastName"));

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mario but I'm facing trouble with implementing it. I am using meta or buddy classes for models and GetCustomAttributes could not find the ViewModelPropertyName attribute

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of setup you have there exactly, but I have edited my answer to what I think you are using. The Extension method will now first take the attribute from the meta class and search its properties for other attributes before returning the required value. I have also created a meta class which is decorated by a new attribute and contains the required properties, instead of the original TestClass.

Comment: I would like to thank you once again for the solution and realizing how much more I need to learn on this stuff.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help. Seeing as though the majority of my other answers are Reflection related, I would also suggest to you to browse through them and see if you get some new information that would be helpful to you.